# Has anyone considered adding gluten to vegan cheese to provide stretchiness?

Tags: veganism

Real mozzarella is stretchy because of its protein. Gluten is stretchy for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Cheese is stretchy when it melts, and wheat gluten doesn't really melt.

Also the protein (casein) that gives cheese its elasticity is very different from the kind of protein in wheat gluten.